# SQL Server : order of linked rows (routes)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with routes and I need to give them actual orders.

The data looks as follows:

```
route | rstart | rfinish | rfrom |  rto  | rorder
--------------------------------------------------
route1|   A    |    E    |   A   |   B   |   0
route1|   A    |    E    |   B   |   E   |   0
route2|   B    |    D    |   B   |   A   |   0
route2|   B    |    D    |   A   |   E   |   0
route2|   B    |    D    |   E   |   D   |   0
```

And I want to update it to

```
route | rstart | rfinish | rfrom |  rto  | rorder
--------------------------------------------------
route1|   A    |    E    |   A   |   B   |   1
route1|   A    |    E    |   B   |   E   |   2
route2|   B    |    D    |   B   |   A   |   1
route2|   B    |    D    |   A   |   E   |   2
route2|   B    |    D    |   E   |   D   |   3
```

The best I've come up with is:

```
UPDATE routes
SET rorder = 1
FROM routes r
WHERE r.rfrom = r.rstart
```

To mark the first edge and

```
UPDATE r
SET rorder = (SELECT TOP 1 r2.rorder
              FROM routes r
              JOIN routes r2 ON r.rfrom = r2.rto 
                              AND r.rstart = r2.rstart 
                              AND r.rfinish = r2.rfinish 
                              AND r.route = r2.route
                              AND r.rorder = 0
                              AND r2.rorder != 0) + 1
FROM routes r
JOIN routes r2 ON r.rfrom = r2.rto 
                 AND r.rstart = r2.rstart 
                 AND r.rfinish = r2.rfinish 
                 AND r.route = r2.route
                 AND r.rorder = 0
                 AND r2.rorder != 0
```

to add the next number for the next edge. The last query should be launched N times where N is the longest route in the table.

I tried `ROW_ORDER()` and it's easy to divide on the right partitions, but I couldn't make `ORDER BY` in it.

It does work but it looks awful. Could you please help me to improve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer above died on the real dataset (200k routes, 1.2m rows). So I solved my problem with variables and the WHILE loop.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT, @maxroute INT
SET @cnt = 1
SET @maxroute = (
                SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM(
                SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM #routes
                GROUP BY name) as tmp
                )
WHILE @cnt <= @maxroute
BEGIN
    IF @cnt = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE r 
            SET r.orderZ = 1
            FROM #routes r
            WHERE r.fromR = r.startR
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE r 
            SET r.orderZ = @cnt
            FROM #routes r
            JOIN #routes r_prev
                ON r.name = r_prev.name AND r.orderZ = 0 AND r_prev.orderZ != 0
                AND r.fromR = r_prev.toR
        END
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a recursive common table expression.
Here is an example with one route, you can modify this to run per route pretty easily.

```
create table #routes
(
    name    varchar(20)
,   startR  varchar(1)
,   endR    varchar(1)
,   fromR   varchar(1)
,   toR     varchar(1)
,   orderZ  int
)

insert into #routes (name, startR, endR, fromR, toR, orderZ)

select 'route2', 'A', 'F', 'E', 'F', 0
union all
select 'route2', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'B', 0
union all
select 'route2', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 0
union all
select 'route2', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'C', 0
union all
select 'route2', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'E', 0


select * from #routes;

with routesTree (name, startR, endR, fromR, toR, orderZ)
as
(
    select
        name, startR, endR, fromR,  toR, orderZ
    from #routes
    where
        startR = fromR
    union all
    select
        R.name, R.startR, R.endR, R.fromR,  R.toR, R.orderZ
    from #routes R
    join routesTree T on T.toR = R.fromR
)

select * into #temp1 FROM routesTree
alter table #temp1
    add RowNum int identity (1,1)

select * From #temp1

drop table #routes
drop table #temp1
```

Comment: Yes, I like your idea!
I just changed it a bit as i on't like the way with the adding of the identity.

I'm posting my answer below as it seems like i cant add it in the replies.

Comment: A run on the real dataset mad me sad. Query was working for more than one and half hour when i stopped it. I made i query using variables and WHILE loop. Not the most SQL-y way but it did the job in 30 seconds.

thanks for your help and an example for recursive queries tho.

Answer (score 0):

Order by getdate() will give the actual order

```
declare @tb table (route  varchar(15),rstart char(1),rfinish char(1),rfrom char(1), rto char(1))
    insert into @tb(route,rstart,rfinish,rfrom,rto) values
    ('route1','A','E','A','B'),
    ('route1','A','E','B','E'),
    ('route2','B','D','B','A'),
    ('route2','B','D','A','E'),
    ('route2','B','D','E','D') 

    select *, row_number() over (partition by route order by getdate()) as rno from @tb`
```

Comment: It's only in that example the rows are in the right order. In fact they come fully mixed. Thus getdate() won't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So using Dave' idea the result is:

```
with routesTree (name, startR, endR, fromR, toR, orderZ)
as
(
    select
        name, startR, endR, fromR,  toR, 1
    from #routes
    where
        startR = fromR
    union all
    select
        R.name, R.startR, R.endR, R.fromR,  R.toR, T.orderZ +1
    from #routes R
    join routesTree T on T.toR = R.fromR and T.name = R.name
)
update r
SET r.orderZ = rt.orderZ
from routesTree rt
JOIN #routes r on r.name = rt.name AND r.fromR = rt.fromR AND r.toR = rt.toR
```